# How to export application level metrics using django-prometheus and prometheus-client?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, metrics, prometheus

I have a Django app exposed to the client as uwsgi server with multiple processes and thread set up in `wsgi.ini`. I read the django-prometheus docs and implemented the models metrics. I can view the models metrics exposed over /metrics endpoint on browser. However the docs say:

> You can add application-level metrics in your code by using 
>   prometheus_client directly. The exporter is global and will pick up 
>   your metrics.

However I cannot see the values of these metrics increasing. They remain 0.0.

I have added **lazy = true** and **enable-threads = true** in my `wsgi.ini` file. Also as doc suggests I have added

```
PROMETHEUS_METRICS_EXPORT_PORT_RANGE = xrange(8001, 8050)
```

in my `settings.py` file to export over different ports for different workers. However still I am not seeing results. What extra needs to be done to finally view  my application level metrics which I have added for different celery workers and apis?

Answer (score 0):

The python prom_client documentation isn't great however it does make it easy to expose application level metrics.

Sounds like you may of not implemented the Prometheus metric types into your app correctly. Point me to the code, and I'll be happy to have a look.

You might want to check out blog post [here](http://burhan.io/flask-application-monitoring-with-prometheus/). Goes through an example in using prom_client on a flask web app.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The URL is broken now and the correct one is https://burhan.io/flask-application-monitoring-with-prometheus-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the metrics into celery workers, it's very likely they fall under the "transient jobs" category, in which case you need to use the [Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) to send your metrics to Prometheus. If that doesn't help, following this guide on [custom application metrics with Prometheus, Django, and Kubernetes](https://labs.meanpug.com/custom-application-metrics-with-django-prometheus-and-kubernetes/) might provide some guidance.